is there a way to "forget" a specific bluetooth device using a command on Android? (name or mac-address)
for a specific setup I need a way to automatically forget a bluetooth device my phone was connected to.
I can use the name or the mac-address, that doesn't matter to me. but I need to be able to disable it without the need to manually interact with the settings app.

AFAIK there's no public method to do so, if you do not want to do it manually, you can do it using reflection using the removeBond method, it is a bit ugly, but it worked for me in old project.

fun removeBond(device: BluetoothDevice) {
    try {
        device::class.java.getMethod("removeBond").invoke(device)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        //RemovingBond failed
    }
}

ADB command should be something like this
adb shell pm grant your.package.name android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
adb shell am start -a android.bluetooth.device.action.REMOVE_BONDED --es android.bluetooth.device.extra.DEVICE "MAC:ADDRESS"



is there a way to use this in adb / shell to test it first smh?

If you are a downvoter, is nice to say WHY you do so ;)

I'm not.. also would be cool if the downvoter of the question would tell me what's wrong. I suspect it might be the same user. Also I'm generally not a fast downvoter. I only downvote if someone acts as if it was a solution they posted, but they obviously only posted a response from an AI output which doesn't work. Especially I wouldn't dislike the only response I get.

and yes.. I get my question is not a great one and matches more a question for an admin forum kind of.. but I don't think there's another place to ask this.. the issue is I  don't really need this functionality in an app directly, but would use it in an app to run on a specific action.

@friendlyjoe no I know you were not the downvoter, but I hate people jsut downvote questions/answers without telling WHY, anyways, if you need more clarify to my answer let me know and I'll try to help you ;)

thank you :)
So I need to build this as a helper app having the intent available and then run the command to trigger this intent right?

Yep, give it a try.
